# Is there any problem with my query?

Tags: php, mysql

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO questions (question_no)
    VALUES ('" . mysql_real_escape_string($i) . "')
    WHERE question_text LIKE ('" . mysql_real_escape_string($val) . "')")
or die('Error, insert query failed');
```

I'm getting the "Error, insert query failed" :(

Comment: why do you make an insert with where clause?

Comment: because insert to where the data match.is it not possible ?

Comment: `INSERT` adds a new record. What do you mean by "data match"? Match with what? Could you please post what you want the table to look like before and after the operation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
mysql_query("insert into questions (question_no) VALUES ('" . mysql_real_escape_string($i) . "') ")or die('Error, insert query failed');
```

no need to add where clause in insert query.

Or use update query to make change in existing records

```
mysql_query("updat questions set question_no = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($i) . "' where question_text like '" . mysql_real_escape_string($val) . "' ")or die('Error, update query failed');
```

Answer (score 4):

You cannot use `WHERE` clause in `INSERT`.

What did you want to achieve with your `WHERE` clause?

**Update:**

If you want to update an existing record, use this:

```
UPDATE  questions
SET     question_no = 'mysql_real_escape_string($i)'
WHERE   question_text LIKE 'mysql_real_escape_string($val)'
```

( quote the query for PHP appropriately, of course )

Answer (score 0):

You should change it to:

```
mysql_query("insert into questions (question_no) 
VALUES ('" . mysql_real_escape_string($i) . "') ")
or die('Error, insert query failed');
```

Note, that where clause in insert values statement is senseless.

Take a look at [mysql doc](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html) regarding inserting a rows. Construction You were trying to use is invalid.